# Embedding YouTube Videos from User Submitted Comments in Django Webpage

Tags: django, youtube, embed, jinja2

I am making a blog webpage in Django, and I have allowed comments for the blog posts. When a user submits a comment, I am able to use a function in my comment model to identify links they included in their text. I can also embed the video back in the template using an iframe and the list of urls the user had in the comment. The issue that I have is that I am wanting to show the embedded video in the exact same spot the user types in a link. For instance, if the user typed one paragraph of text, and then pasted in a YouTube link, and then they typed one more paragraph, I would want the video to be embedded in between the paragraphs. I have tried several things, but I just haven't been able to figure it out yet. I appreciate any answer I get. Here is the code for the comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey('forum.Thread', related_name='comments')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='guest')
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def get_youtube_urls(self):
        urls = []
        youtube_regex = (
            r'(https?://)?(www\.)?'
            '(youtube|youtu|youtube-nocookie)\.(com|be)/'
            '(watch\?v=|embed/|v/|.+\?v=)?([^&=%\?]{11})')

        matches = re.findall(youtube_regex, self.text)

        for url in matches:
            urls.append(url[5])

        return urls
```

And here is the section of my template that deals with the comments:

```
<div class="comment">
    <strong>Reply from user {{ comment.username }}</strong>
    <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks|urlize }}</p>
    {% if comment.get_youtube_urls %}
        {% for url in comment.get_youtube_urls %}
            <div style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:56.25%"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{url}}?ecver=2" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" style="position:absolute;width:50%;height:50%;left:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</div>
</div>
```

Does any one have any ideas on how to embed video where the user places the link in the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Previously, I explained such as below because I created an issue [save regex permalink not work well](https://github.com/rscarvalho/pyregex/issues/26).

So, if you want to test it you can try manually.
I check your regex patterns on http://www.pyregex.com with;

**1.** mode: `findall`

**2.** patterns:

```
(https?://)?(www\.)?(youtube|youtu|youtube-nocookie)\.(com|be)/(watch\?v=|embed/|v/|.+\?v=)?([^&=%\?]{11})
```

**3.** test strings:

```
https://youtu.be/yVpbFMhOAwE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Z5EjAmZS1o

https://www.youtube.com/embed/yVpbFMhOAwE

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Tlf00NT6mig" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KQzCxdO3hvo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VslLZcV9ZcU&list=RD8Z5EjAmZS1o&index=2
```

**4.** result:

```
["https://","","youtu","be","","yVpbFMhOAwE"]
["https://","www.","youtube","com","watch?v=","8Z5EjAmZS1o"]
["https://","www.","youtube","com","embed/","yVpbFMhOAwE"]
["https://","www.","youtube","com","embed/","Tlf00NT6mig"]
["https://","www.","youtube","com","embed/","KQzCxdO3hvo"]
["https://","www.","youtube","com","watch?v=","VslLZcV9ZcU"]
```

I think you should do this to get the video id;

```
def get_youtube_urls(self):

    youtube_regex = (
        r'(https?://)?(www\.)?'
        '(youtube|youtu|youtube-nocookie)\.(com|be)/'
        '(watch\?v=|embed/|v/|.+\?v=)?([^&=%\?]{11})')

    matches = re.findall(youtube_regex, self.text)

    urls = []
    for url in matches:
        id = url[-1]        # from last index of `matches` list.
        if len(id) == 11:   # check if `id` is valid or not.
            urls.append(id)
    return urls
```

If it doesn't work, I suggest you to change the value of `youtube_regex` above with this *(without saving in the tuple)*.

```
youtube_regex = r'(https?://)?(www\.)?(youtube|youtu|youtube-nocookie)\.(com|be)/(watch\?v=|embed/|v/|.+\?v=)?([^&=%\?]{11})'

# OR, recomended to use this;

youtube_regex = r'http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?(youtube|youtu|youtube-nocookie)\.(com|be)/(watch\?v=|embed/|v/|.+\?v=)?([^&=%\?]{11})'
```

#### Update

To get the correct position, I suggest you to use `finditer`;

```
>>> youtube_regex = r'http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?(youtube|youtu|youtube-nocookie)\.(com|be)/(watch\?v=|embed/|v/|.+\?v=)?([^&=%\?]{11})'
>>> pattern = re.compile(youtube_regex)
>>> [{'origin': m.group(), 'id': m.group(4), 'position': m.start()} for m in pattern.finditer(test_strings) ]
[
  {'position': 0, 'id': 'yVpbFMhOAwE', 'origin': 'https://youtu.be/yVpbFMhOAwE'}, 
  {'position': 30, 'id': '8Z5EjAmZS1o', 'origin': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Z5EjAmZS1o'}, 
  {'position': 75, 'id': 'yVpbFMhOAwE', 'origin': 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/yVpbFMhOAwE'}, 
  {'position': 156, 'id': 'Tlf00NT6mig', 'origin': 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Tlf00NT6mig'}, 
  {'position': 280, 'id': 'KQzCxdO3hvo', 'origin': 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/KQzCxdO3hvo'}, 
  {'position': 366, 'id': 'VslLZcV9ZcU', 'origin': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VslLZcV9ZcU'}
]
>>
```

And then, handle it with templatetags. this script below isn't completed yet, you need to remove the tag such as `<iframe`, or else from the origin text comment..

```
import re
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

def iframe_video(id):
    """
    return html string iframe video from the `id`.
    """
    return '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{}"></iframe>'.format(id)

@register.filter
def safe_comment(text_comment):
    """
    {{ comment.text|safe_comment|linebreaks|urlize }}
    """
    youtube_regex = (r'http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?'
                     '(youtube|youtu|youtube-nocookie)\.(com|be)/'
                     '(watch\?v=|embed/|v/|.+\?v=)?([^&=%\?]{11})')
    pattern = re.compile(youtube_regex)
    matches = [
        {'origin': m.group(), 'id': m.group(4), 'position': m.start()}
        for m in pattern.finditer(text_comment)
    ]
    for match in matches:
        id = match['id']
        origin = match['origin']
        position = match['position']

        # text_comment.replace(origin, iframe_video(id))
        # do something to replace tag <iframe, or else..
    return mark_safe(text_comment)
```

Comment: Ok, that would give the the correct values into the list. But what about placing those values into their correct position inside of the template?

Comment: I think you can handle it with `finditer` inside a custom templatetag... please checkout my latest update..

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think this will work when I try it. I need to study regex more, because I am not very familiar with it.